# Sphinx4 speech recognition trasncribe demo not working accurately for short wav file

Tags: android, speech-recognition, audio-recording, sphinx4, transcription

i had just implemetned the transcriber demo for the transcribe the audio file
..
My audio file is .wav file which consist only names like "BHAVIK" "ANKIT"
"SAGAR"

My grammer File Consist of this grammer as follows: -

public  = (JAY)|(SAGAR)|(BHAVIK)|(ANKIT)|(MIRAJ)|(YAGNESH);

But Problem is that the transcriber demo not provide the correct result ..its
just providing me somthing other when i give .wav file of "JAY" ..its not give
the correct result..

Why this happening?
my .wav file is here u can hear..

http://www.crocko.com/62E9703E57844AE6B7A172D5CBBB8DE3/Vocaroo_s0dmd1kxVSfJ.wav

Please Help me...
Thanks in Advance
I had implemetned the logic in adnroid like this..i m using one class name as extaudiorecorder.

public class ExtAudioRecorder

{
    private final static int[] sampleRates = {44100, 22050, 11025, 16000};

```
public static ExtAudioRecorder getInstanse(Boolean recordingCompressed)
{
    ExtAudioRecorder result = null;

    if(recordingCompressed)
    {
        result = new ExtAudioRecorder(  false, 
                                        AudioSource.MIC, 
                                        sampleRates[3], 
                                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    }
    else
    {
        int i=0;
        do
        {
            result = new ExtAudioRecorder(  true, 
                                            AudioSource.MIC, 
                                            sampleRates[i], 
                                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        } while((++i<sampleRates.length) & !(result.getState() == ExtAudioRecorder.State.INITIALIZING));
    }
    return result;
}

/**
* INITIALIZING : recorder is initializing;
* READY : recorder has been initialized, recorder not yet started
* RECORDING : recording
* ERROR : reconstruction needed
* STOPPED: reset needed
*/
public enum State {INITIALIZING, READY, RECORDING, ERROR, STOPPED};

public static final boolean RECORDING_UNCOMPRESSED = true;
public static final boolean RECORDING_COMPRESSED = false;

// The interval in which the recorded samples are output to the file
// Used only in uncompressed mode
private static final int TIMER_INTERVAL = 120;

// Toggles uncompressed recording on/off; RECORDING_UNCOMPRESSED / RECORDING_COMPRESSED
private boolean         rUncompressed;

// Recorder used for uncompressed recording
private AudioRecord     audioRecorder = null;

// Recorder used for compressed recording
private MediaRecorder   mediaRecorder = null;

// Stores current amplitude (only in uncompressed mode)
private int             cAmplitude= 0;

// Output file path
private String          filePath = null;

// Recorder state; see State
private State           state;

// File writer (only in uncompressed mode)
private RandomAccessFile randomAccessWriter;

// Number of channels, sample rate, sample size(size in bits), buffer size, audio source, sample size(see AudioFormat)
private short                    nChannels;
private int                      sRate;
private short                    bSamples;
private int                      bufferSize;
private int                      aSource;
private int                      aFormat;

// Number of frames written to file on each output(only in uncompressed mode)
private int                      framePeriod;

// Buffer for output(only in uncompressed mode)
private byte[]                   buffer;

// Number of bytes written to file after header(only in uncompressed mode)
// after stop() is called, this size is written to the header/data chunk in the wave file
private int                      payloadSize;

/**
*
* Returns the state of the recorder in a RehearsalAudioRecord.State typed object.
* Useful, as no exceptions are thrown.
*
* @return recorder state
*/
public State getState()
{
    return state;
}

/*
*
* Method used for recording.
*
*/
private AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener updateListener = new AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener()
{
    public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder)
    {
        audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); // Fill buffer
        try
        { 
            randomAccessWriter.write(buffer); // Write buffer to file
            payloadSize += buffer.length;
            if (bSamples == 16)
            {
                for (int i=0; i<buffer.length/2; i++)
                { // 16bit sample size
                    short curSample = getShort(buffer[i*2], buffer[i*2+1]);
                    if (curSample > cAmplitude)
                    { // Check amplitude
                        cAmplitude = curSample;
                    }
                }
            }
            else    
            { // 8bit sample size
                for (int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++)
                {
                    if (buffer[i] > cAmplitude)
                    { // Check amplitude
                        cAmplitude = buffer[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Error occured in updateListener, recording is aborted");
            //stop();
        }
    }

    public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder)
    {
        // NOT USED
    }
};
/** 
 * 
 * 
 * Default constructor
 * 
 * Instantiates a new recorder, in case of compressed recording the parameters can be left as 0.
 * In case of errors, no exception is thrown, but the state is set to ERROR
 * 
 */ 
public ExtAudioRecorder(boolean uncompressed, int audioSource, int sampleRate, int channelConfig, int audioFormat)
{
    try
    {
        rUncompressed = uncompressed;
        if (rUncompressed)
        { // RECORDING_UNCOMPRESSED
            if (audioFormat == AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
            {
                bSamples = 16;
            }
            else
            {
                bSamples = 8;
            }

            if (channelConfig == AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO)
            {
                nChannels = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                nChannels = 2;
            }

            aSource = audioSource;
            sRate   = sampleRate;
            aFormat = audioFormat;

            framePeriod = sampleRate * TIMER_INTERVAL / 1000;
            bufferSize = framePeriod * 2 * bSamples * nChannels / 8;
            if (bufferSize < AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat))
            { // Check to make sure buffer size is not smaller than the smallest allowed one 
                bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                // Set frame period and timer interval accordingly
                framePeriod = bufferSize / ( 2 * bSamples * nChannels / 8 );
                Log.w(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Increasing buffer size to " + Integer.toString(bufferSize));
            }

            audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

            if (audioRecorder.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                throw new Exception("AudioRecord initialization failed");
            audioRecorder.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(updateListener);
            audioRecorder.setPositionNotificationPeriod(framePeriod);
        } else
        { // RECORDING_COMPRESSED
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);               
        }
        cAmplitude = 0;
        filePath = null;
        state = State.INITIALIZING;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e.getMessage() != null)
        {
            Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Unknown error occured while initializing recording");
        }
        state = State.ERROR;
    }
}

/**
 * Sets output file path, call directly after construction/reset.
 *  
 * @param output file path
 * 
 */
public void setOutputFile(String argPath)
{
    try
    {
        if (state == State.INITIALIZING)
        {
            filePath = argPath;
            if (!rUncompressed)
            {
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filePath);                  
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e.getMessage() != null)
        {
            Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Unknown error occured while setting output path");
        }
        state = State.ERROR;
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * Returns the largest amplitude sampled since the last call to this method.
 * 
 * @return returns the largest amplitude since the last call, or 0 when not in recording state. 
 * 
 */
public int getMaxAmplitude()
{
    if (state == State.RECORDING)
    {
        if (rUncompressed)
        {
            int result = cAmplitude;
            cAmplitude = 0;
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException e)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


/**
 * 
* Prepares the recorder for recording, in case the recorder is not in the INITIALIZING state and the file path was not set
* the recorder is set to the ERROR state, which makes a reconstruction necessary.
* In case uncompressed recording is toggled, the header of the wave file is written.
* In case of an exception, the state is changed to ERROR
*    
*/
public void prepare()
{
    try
    {
        if (state == State.INITIALIZING)
        {
            if (rUncompressed)
            {
                if ((audioRecorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) & (filePath != null))
                {
                    // write file header

                    randomAccessWriter = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");

                    randomAccessWriter.setLength(0); // Set file length to 0, to prevent unexpected behavior in case the file already existed
                    randomAccessWriter.writeBytes("RIFF");
                    randomAccessWriter.writeInt(0); // Final file size not known yet, write 0 
                    randomAccessWriter.writeBytes("WAVE");
                    randomAccessWriter.writeBytes("fmt ");
                    randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(16)); // Sub-chunk size, 16 for PCM
                    randomAccessWriter.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short) 1)); // AudioFormat, 1 for PCM
                    randomAccessWriter.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(nChannels));// Number of channels, 1 for mono, 2 for stereo
                    randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(sRate)); // Sample rate
                    randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(sRate*bSamples*nChannels/8)); // Byte rate, SampleRate*NumberOfChannels*BitsPerSample/8
                    randomAccessWriter.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short)(nChannels*bSamples/8))); // Block align, NumberOfChannels*BitsPerSample/8
                    randomAccessWriter.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(bSamples)); // Bits per sample
                    randomAccessWriter.writeBytes("data");
                    randomAccessWriter.writeInt(0); // Data chunk size not known yet, write 0

                    buffer = new byte[framePeriod*bSamples/8*nChannels];
                    state = State.READY;
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "prepare() method called on uninitialized recorder");
                    state = State.ERROR;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mediaRecorder.prepare();
                state = State.READY;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "prepare() method called on illegal state");
            release();
            state = State.ERROR;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        if (e.getMessage() != null)
        {
            Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Unknown error occured in prepare()");
        }
        state = State.ERROR;
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 *  Releases the resources associated with this class, and removes the unnecessary files, when necessary
 *  
 */
public void release()
{
    if (state == State.RECORDING)
    {
        stop();
    }
    else
    {
        if ((state == State.READY) & (rUncompressed))
        {
            try
            {
                randomAccessWriter.close(); // Remove prepared file
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "I/O exception occured while closing output file");
            }
            (new File(filePath)).delete();
        }
    }

    if (rUncompressed)
    {
        if (audioRecorder != null)
        {
            audioRecorder.release();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (mediaRecorder != null)
        {
            mediaRecorder.release();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * Resets the recorder to the INITIALIZING state, as if it was just created.
 * In case the class was in RECORDING state, the recording is stopped.
 * In case of exceptions the class is set to the ERROR state.
 * 
 */
public void reset()
{
    try
    {
        if (state != State.ERROR)
        {
            release();
            filePath = null; // Reset file path
            cAmplitude = 0; // Reset amplitude
            if (rUncompressed)
            {
                audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(aSource, sRate, nChannels+1, aFormat, bufferSize);
            }
            else
            {
                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            }
            state = State.INITIALIZING;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
        state = State.ERROR;
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * Starts the recording, and sets the state to RECORDING.
 * Call after prepare().
 * 
 */
public void start()
{
    if (state == State.READY)
    {
        if (rUncompressed)
        {
            payloadSize = 0;
            audioRecorder.startRecording();
            audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        }
        else
        {
            mediaRecorder.start();
        }
        state = State.RECORDING;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "start() called on illegal state");
        state = State.ERROR;
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 *  Stops the recording, and sets the state to STOPPED.
 * In case of further usage, a reset is needed.
 * Also finalizes the wave file in case of uncompressed recording.
 * 
 */
public void stop()
{
    if (state == State.RECORDING)
    {
        if (rUncompressed)
        {
            audioRecorder.stop();

            try
            {
                randomAccessWriter.seek(4); // Write size to RIFF header
                randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(36+payloadSize));

                randomAccessWriter.seek(40); // Write size to Subchunk2Size field
                randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(payloadSize));

                randomAccessWriter.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "I/O exception occured while closing output file");
                state = State.ERROR;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
        }
        state = State.STOPPED;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "stop() called on illegal state");
        state = State.ERROR;
    }
}

/* 
 * 
 * Converts a byte[2] to a short, in LITTLE_ENDIAN format
 * 
 */
private short getShort(byte argB1, byte argB2)
{
    return (short)(argB1 | (argB2 << 8));
}
```

}

And i m using that class in my main activity as here ..i m recording sound on button click and stop it on another button click

```
    package com.test.android_recorder;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    public class AndroidRecorder extends Activity {
         ExtAudioRecorder extAudioRecorder;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(com.test.android_recorder.R.layout.activity_android_recorder);
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            Button buttonstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);

            // Start recording
               extAudioRecorder = ExtAudioRecorder.getInstanse(true);   


            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View v)
              {

    TextView txt1=(TextView)findViewById(com.test.android_recorder.R.id.textView1);
                  txt1.setText("Button clciked");

                     // Compressed recording (AMR)
                        //extAudioRecorder = ExtAudioRecorder.getInstanse(false); // Uncompressed recording (WAV)

                        extAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/javarecorder");
                        extAudioRecorder.prepare();
                        extAudioRecorder.start();


                  // ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
                 //iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
            });



            buttonstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View v)
              {

    //TextView txt1=(TextView)findViewById(com.test.android_recorder.R.id.textView1);
                 // txt1.setText("Button clciked");
                  // ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
                 //iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                  // Stop recording
                  extAudioRecorder.stop();
                  extAudioRecorder.release();
              }
            });




            /*


    */
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(com.test.android_recorder.R.menu.activity_android_recorder, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }


When i run this code then nothing is happening and in logcat i have following error

Start() called in illegel state.
preapare() called in illegel state.
stop() called in illegel state.

Please Help me Out
```

Answer (score 3):

One problem I've seen throw off people using Wav files with other recognizers is that the file must be in a supported format. WAV is a generic file type that can support audio in different formats (sample size, mono/stereo, different sample rates, etc.). Recognizers aren't as flexible as media players so you have to make sure your wav file is in a format the recognizer handles.

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq says:

> The top reasons of the bad accuracy are:
>
> 1. The mismatch of the sample rate of the incoming audio. It must be
>    16khz 16bit mono little-endian file. You need to fix sample rate of
>    the source with resampling. Verify sample rate in order to test that.

If your file is not in this format, you can resample with [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)

By the way, I was not able to play your wav file with QuickTime or with Windows Media player. What format or encoding is it in?

Comment: Thanks for the really good guidance..i ahd record that wav file from this online wav recorder site http://vocaroo.com/

Comment: I want to generate that 16khz 16bit mono little-endian file .but i cant find any recorder that have facilty to confingure the sound file with the above specification.can u suggest me?i had donwload audacity.but cant find that options in that 16khz 16 bit mono little endian

Comment: One thing more i wanna ask that how can i record the 16khz 16 bit mono little endian .wav file with the android device.?or any converter code in java that converts the .wav file with specified sampling rate ?

Comment: If you are recording in Audacity, go to Edit>Preferences. Then select Quality. Then set Sampling to "16000 Hz" and 16-bit. You can also st the Devices to default to 1 channel (mono). After making your recording you can save it by selecting File>Export and specifying file type as WAV signed 16 bit PCM. To resample an existing file try: Tracks->Stereo to Mono then Tracks->Resample (to 16000 Hz).

Comment: http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/WAV - "WAV files always have little-endian  byte order"

Comment: On Android you might try - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tylab.waverec16.lite

Comment: thnax for this usuefull guidance...i had stored the wav file from audacity and it was so accurate//  evn i had tried with your link for android but i want to create it programmitacly..