# WAV Audio recording for Sphinx-4 fail

Tags: macos, audio, demo, sphinx4, audacity

I recorded a wav file using Audacity for testing transcriber demo from Sphinx-4, I followed the instruction in this post: [Sphinx4 speech recognition trasncribe demo not working accurately for short wav file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247921/sphinx4-speech-recognition-trasncribe-demo-not-working-accurately-for-short-wav)

especially in this answer:

```
It must be 16khz 16bit mono little-endian file.
```

I even reduced the noise afterward. But I get the null error when I try to print the hypothesis which mean there was a problem with my recording:

```
Loading models...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at transcriber.Transcriber.main(Transcriber.java:41)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 minutes 14 seconds)
```

Line 41 where I print the hypothesis. what can I do to get it work?
Thanks

**Edit**:
The code is:

```
package transcriber;

import java.net.URL;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.WordResult;

/**
 *
 * @author ha
 */
public class Transcriber {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
System.out.println("Loading models...");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        // Load model from the jar
        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz/dict/cmudict.0.6d");        
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath("models/language/en-us.lm.dmp");

        StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

        URL audioUrl = new URL("file:WAV/Hello.wav");
        recognizer.startRecognition(audioUrl.openStream());

        SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
        System.out.println(recognizer.getResult().getHypothesis());

        while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
            System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n",
                              result.getHypothesis());
        }

        System.out.println("Stop Recognition..");
        recognizer.stopRecognition();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this has to do with the recording? NullPointerException can happen because there's just a mistake in your code (something is null).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because of my recording, because when I run it with the demo audio it works very fine :/

Comment: When you ask about exceptions ALWAYS provide full exception text

Comment: I did edit the question. Hope it would help more to find an answer.Thanks

Comment: Share the file you are trying too.

Comment: Sure, http://www.mediafire.com/listen/e44iwcm1is1k76v/Hello.wav

Comment: I tried your audio file with Transcriber demo from the tutorial and got correct results. Make sure you can reproduce my results first, then start to write your own code.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. how can I set the acoustic  model to en-us generic model? I tried downloading the folder from the website then copy the en-us folder into bld. but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
System.out.println(recognizer.getResult().getHypothesis());
```

with

```
System.out.println(result.getHypothesis());
```